# SQL SELECT clause with WHERE statement for specific order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a through table, `doctor_specialties` that has a column ordinal that I would like to use in order to create a column named `primary_specialty` and also `secondary_specialty`. The logic for `primary_specialty` is `WHERE ordinal == 1`.

How can I add the `primary_specialty` and `secondary_specialty` columns? One approach would be to use a `WHERE` statement with the `INNER JOIN` but I think that would be less efficient?

```
SELECT pd.name AS "doctor_name", 
       s.name AS "primary_specialty" WHERE ds.ordinal == 1

FROM doctor_profiles AS dp
     INNER JOIN doctor_specialties AS ds on dp.id = ds.doctor_profile_id
     INNER JOIN specialties AS s on ds.specialty_id = s.id
```

Desired output is

```
name    primary_specialty    secondary_specialty
Josh    Dermatology,         Cosmetic Dermatology
Linda   Primary Care         null
```

Comment: Simplify your example. All those tables can't be needed to explain the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: You want to get both `primary_speciality` and `secondary_specialty` when `doctor_specialties.ordinal = 1`, right? Else it would be `NULL` for the two columns?

Comment: @Edhrendal if there is a `doctor_specialty` with ordinal = 1, populate with specialty.name. Same for `secondary_specialty` where ordinal = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to achive this by using case statement. example is shared below

```
SELECT pd.name AS "doctor_name", 
 case when ds.ordinal = 1 then s.name end as "primary_specialty",
 case when ds.ordinal <> 1 then s.name end as "secondary_specialty"
 FROM doctor_profiles AS dp
 INNER JOIN doctor_specialties AS ds on dp.id = ds.doctor_profile_id
 INNER JOIN specialties AS s on ds.specialty_id = s.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT dp.name AS "doctor_name", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ds.ordinal = 1 THEN s.name END) AS "primary_specialty",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ds.ordinal != 2 THEN s.name END) AS "secondary_specialty"

FROM doctor_profiles AS dp
     INNER JOIN doctor_specialties AS ds on dp.id = ds.doctor_profile_id
     INNER JOIN specialties AS s on ds.specialty_id = s.id

GROUP BY pd.name
```

You can alter the existing, or use additional `MAX` aggregates containing `CASE` expressions, in order to implement the logic for secondary specialties.